# Is ContactsContract.Contacts by default empty?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-contacts

Is ContactsContract.Contacts by default empty? If so, how do I add some test data to it?

Otherwise, I must be doing something wrong/omitting something, as this Activity displays completely empty.

```
public class Authorize_Activity extends ListActivity {

    Cursor mContacts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Return all contacts, ordered by name
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }; // Would like the phone num, too
        mContacts = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        // Display all contacts in a ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mContacts, 
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }); 

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

My understanding is that android's simple_list_item_1 should provide the "View" so that I don't need to call SetContentView().

But although my Activity is displaying, no data appears in it. So...am I just missing Contacts data, or is something more nefarious afoot?

Comment: Not sure - is this on an emulator? If so then it wouldn't surprise me if it is empty by default. Try using the emulator's contacts / people app to add some fake contacts.

Comment: That was it; that's what you get for assuming: I assumed they (the Googlers/Androidheads) would supply a few random/bogus Contacts to the emulator, like Sergey Brin, Larry Page, Jimmy Page, etc. Once I added a few (not those), it seems to work fine.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer. It seems it may well be useful to other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this on an emulator?

If so then it wouldn't surprise me if the contacts list is empty by default. Try using the emulator's contacts / people app to add some fake contacts.